# processing multiple files with gulp-pug

Tags: gulp, pug

I want to preprocess my pug files to html files using gulp. Currently I have this in my 'default' script:

```
gulp.watch([
    'app/partials/**.pug',
    'app/index.pug'], ['views-compile']
);
```

My 'views-compile' function is as follows

```
var pug = require('gulp-pug2');

gulp.task('views-compile', function(){
    return gulp.src([
        'app/partials/**.pug',
        'app/index.pug'
    ])
    .pipe(pug.compile())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('app/views/'))
})
```

When I run this task I get an error that the file already exists

```
C:\dev\my-project>gulp views-compile
[09:18:01] Using gulpfile C:\dev\my-project\gulpfile.js
[09:18:01] Starting 'views-compile'...
[09:18:01] 'views-compile' errored after 190 ms
[09:18:01] Error: EEXIST: file already exists, mkdir 'C:\dev\my-project\app\views'
    at Error (native)
```

What can I do to solve this problem and process all my pug files using an *.pug watch?

Comment: Check that `app/views` isn't the name of an existing file. Other than that you'll have to provide a [mcve] that reproduces the problem if you want to have any chance of somebody being able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this with the following steps:

1. Added NODE_PATH as system variabele with value:
   %AppData%\npm\node_modules
2. Added '%AppData%\npm\' in PATH as first
3. Install gulp globally
4. Install gulp local in project
5. Install gulp-cli globally
6. Install gulp-cli local in project

Log off and on, to apply settings. 
On different places on the internet, you find to add %AppData%\npm\node_modules in PATH but in my case that was not working.